# Reading JPEGs in Java

Tags: java, jpeg, javax.imageio

I'm attempting to get a JPEG into a `BufferedImage` to display on a `JPanel` . However, `javax.imageio.ImageIO.read()` seems to be very fussy about the JPEGs it processes, often throwing an `IIOException`. The same JPEGs open fine in pretty much any image reader you'd care to name.

I've looked at Apache's [Sanselan](http://commons.apache.org/imaging/) and [JAI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/current-142188.html). But Sanselan can't process JPEGs and JAI isn't available for 64-bit Windows platforms and doesn't seem to be maintained (the last update was in 2006). A previous [answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177655/java-imageio-iioexception-unsupported-image-type) suggested  `com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec`, but this was deprecated in Java 5 and has disappeared in 7.

Are these my only options? Are there really no Java libraries capable of robustly reading JPEGs into a `BufferedImage`?

Comment: Try using another picture to test it.

Comment: @Jason: Another picture is not the point. Some pictures do indeed load fine. The problem is that several don't. When using pictures from diverse sources, not every picture is going to be whatever `ImageIO.read()`'s definition of a "perfect" JPEG is.

Comment: Can you link to an example image? Have you identified any variation from the [nominal standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG)?

Comment: May be you can get answer from this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999528/is-there-a-100-java-alternative-to-imageio-for-reading-jpeg-files

Comment: The one linked to in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999528/is-there-a-100-java-alternative-to-imageio-for-reading-jpeg-files is an example. This is a known issue with ImageIO (see link). I'm looking specifically for an alternative library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Legacy [Toolkit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html) methods such as [createImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createImage%28java.lang.String%29) and [getImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getImage%28java.lang.String%29) are known to be more lenient than `ImageIO`.

Werner Randelshofer also wrote a [Service Provider](http://www.randelshofer.ch/blog/2011/08/reading-cmyk-jpeg-images-with-java-imageio/) to read CMYK JPEGs with `ImageIO`.

By combining both approaches (try every possible `ImageReader` and then fallback to `Toolkit`) you will be able to handle a reasonable number of JPEG Images.

[Reading JPEGs with CMYK profile](http://www.javahelp.info/2009/10/31/reading-jpegs-with-cmyk-profile/) may be a interesting read.

Comment: This seems like it could work. I won't have time to work on this project for a while, so I'm going to accept this answer. It really does suck that there isn't a good library for hassle-free image processing in Java, not even a third-party one. Surely people have needed something like this before...