# javax.imageio.ImageIO: "IIOException: Unsupported image type" error when loading a gif file

Tags: gif, javax.imageio

I want to load the following gif file using

```
ImageIO.read(new URL("http://logos.affili.net/120x40/10421.gif"))
```

and this line throws

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Unsupported Image Type
```

Why? Is there a way to load such files? I only need to load them for determining image size (height and weight) in pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is:

a) The image in question `"http://logos.affili.net/120x40/10421.gif"` is not a GIF despite it's extension, it's a JPEG (this is actually OK for ImageIO, as it doen't look at the file extension anyway, but it's part of the analysis).

b) Further, the image is a CMYK (YCCK) JPEG. The standard `JPEGImageReader` does not handle CMYK JPEGs, and causes the exception you experience.

You can use my [JPEG ImageIO plugin](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/tree/master/imageio/imageio-jpeg) to read such files, or look at the other alternatives like Sanselan/Commons Imaging, JAI etc.

See [Java ImageIO IIOException: Unsupported image type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177655/java-imageio-iioexception-unsupported-image-type) and [Pure Java alternative to JAI ImageIO for detecting CMYK images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829428/pure-java-alternative-to-jai-imageio-for-detecting-cmyk-images) for more information.