# what library I need so I can access this com.sun.image.codec.jpeg in Java?

Tags: java, image-processing, jpeg

I'm creating an image watermarking program in java and I imported the followings:

```
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec;
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGEncodeParam;
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageEncoder;
```

but I get an error that says:

> Access restriction: The type `JPEGCodec` is not accesible due to restriction on required library `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar`

Does someone know a way to solve this, or what library should I add in order to access that and where I find that library?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906673/import-com-sun-image-codec-jpeg

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look here [Link](http://forums.dzone.com/eclipse/384-access-restriction-problems.html)

```
1. Open project properties.
2. Select Java Build Path node.
3. Select Libraries tab.
4. Remove JRE System Library.
5. Add Library JRE System Library.
```

As `Milad` suggested

> Even though this WILL work, this goes against all recommended Java Runtime policies. The best practice is to avoid using rt.jar (or any other Sun supplied runtime library for that matter, like tools.jar)

Comment: Even though this WILL work, this goes against all recommended Java Runtime policies. The best practice is to avoid using rt.jar (or any other Sun supplied runtime library for that matter, like tools.jar)

Comment: i included your comment in my answer

Comment: :) I just wanted to make sure that the answers being given were comprehensive. Sorry if I sounded arrogant or anything.

Comment: No,its fine. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

These are in rt.jar, the jar file used as run-time facilities by the JVM, and I would strongly recommend you against adding it as a dependency to your project.

See why [here](http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/faq/faq-sun-packages.html).

The correct way to do what you want to do is described [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html).

Comment: So I should add rt.jar as an external jar to my build path?

Comment: Yeah, you will be, even though I'd still advise you against it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that you're importing libraries from the `sun.com.*` package. [Oracle actually discourages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html) the use of these packages, since they could be removed in future releases or may not be available in all JVM implementations.

It's possible that your IDE (which one are you using?) is configured for generating errors if you try to import `sun.com.*` libraries, in that case a configuration change will allow you to use those libraries, but it wouldn't be a good idea anyway. You should look for other alternatives to the functionality you seek, using libraries with no access restrictions.

Also, if what you want is to simply read or write a JPEG file, take a look at the [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) class, there are plenty of useful methods in there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your jre system library is 1.8

or eclipse: Project Properties > java compiler > Errors/Warnings > Deprecated API

change Error to ignore/warning