# AWS Elastic Beanstalk error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageEncoder

Tags: java, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am getting the following error when attempting to use Linux, Tomcat 8, and Java 8 on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageEncoder
```

Comment: similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869912/what-library-i-need-so-i-can-acces-this-com-sun-image-codec-jpeg-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.\*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906673/import-com-sun-image-codec-jpeg)

You're not supposed to use SUN classes.They can't be depended on to be available, Follow the steps in the answer I linked to

Comment: Please provide more context around the error -- for example, do you get this at runtime, during deployment, etc.