# error: package com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util does not exist

Tags: java, maven, bamboo

I am trying to build my project through bamboo CI with `Maven`. The project is building correctly on my local machine but when i am trying to build it using Amazon EC2 its giving me following errors.

```
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [INFO] 8 warnings 
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\presentation\images\ImageCacher.java:[7,50] error: package com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util does not exist
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\presentation\images\ImageCacher.java:[16,22] error: package javax.media.jai does not exist
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\presentation\templates\HTMLLoader.java:[17,26] error: package quicktime.std.image does not exist
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\application\functions\ImageFunctions.java:[20,31] error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\application\functions\ImageFunctions.java:[21,31] error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\application\functions\ImageFunctions.java:[22,31] error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\application\functions\ImageFunctions.java:[23,31] error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\application\functions\ImageFunctions.java:[276,41] error: cannot find symbol
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\presentation\images\ImageWatermark.java:[21,31] error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\presentation\images\ImageWatermark.java:[22,31] error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\presentation\images\ImageWatermark.java:[23,31] error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\application\functions\ImageFunctions.java:[157,25] error: cannot find symbol
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\application\functions\ImageFunctions.java:[236,21] error: cannot find symbol
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\application\functions\ImageFunctions.java:[327,12] error: cannot find symbol
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\application\functions\ImageFunctions.java:[327,39] error: cannot find symbol
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\application\functions\ImageFunctions.java:[328,12] error: cannot find symbol
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\presentation\images\ImageWatermark.java:[69,6] error: cannot find symbol
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\presentation\images\ImageWatermark.java:[69,33] error: cannot find symbol
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\presentation\images\ImageWatermark.java:[160,6] error: cannot find symbol
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\presentation\images\ImageWatermark.java:[160,33] error: cannot find symbol
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [INFO] 20 errors 
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [INFO] Total time: 21.490s
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [INFO] Finished at: Wed Jan 08 10:50:16 GMT 2014
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [INFO] Final Memory: 24M/451M
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project portalogue: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\presentation\images\ImageCacher.java:[7,50] error: package com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util does not exist
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\presentation\images\ImageCacher.java:[16,22] error: package javax.media.jai does not exist
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\presentation\templates\HTMLLoader.java:[17,26] error: package quicktime.std.image does not exist
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\application\functions\ImageFunctions.java:[20,31] error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\application\functions\ImageFunctions.java:[21,31] error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\application\functions\ImageFunctions.java:[22,31] error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\application\functions\ImageFunctions.java:[23,31] error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\application\functions\ImageFunctions.java:[276,41] error: cannot find symbol
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\presentation\images\ImageWatermark.java:[21,31] error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\presentation\images\ImageWatermark.java:[22,31] error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\presentation\images\ImageWatermark.java:[23,31] error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\application\functions\ImageFunctions.java:[157,25] error: cannot find symbol
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\application\functions\ImageFunctions.java:[236,21] error: cannot find symbol
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\application\functions\ImageFunctions.java:[327,12] error: cannot find symbol
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\application\functions\ImageFunctions.java:[327,39] error: cannot find symbol
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\application\functions\ImageFunctions.java:[328,12] error: cannot find symbol
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\presentation\images\ImageWatermark.java:[69,6] error: cannot find symbol
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\presentation\images\ImageWatermark.java:[69,33] error: cannot find symbol
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\presentation\images\ImageWatermark.java:[160,6] error: cannot find symbol
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] \build-dir\MAV-POR-CCB\src\main\java\com\xti\portalogue\presentation\images\ImageWatermark.java:[160,33] error: cannot find symbol
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project portalogue: Compilation failure
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16        at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:656)
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16        at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16        ... 19 more
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] 
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] 
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
build   08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
simple  08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    Failing task since return code of [c:\opt\maven-3.0\bin\mvn.bat --batch-mode -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\Bamboo\AppData\Local\Temp\MAV-POR-CCB -X clean compile] was 1 while expected 0
simple  08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    Finished task 'Build Portalogue'
simple  08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    Running post build plugin 'Artifact Copier'
simple  08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    Running post build plugin 'NCover Results Collector'
simple  08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    Running post build plugin 'Clover Results Collector'
simple  08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    Finalising the build...
simple  08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    Stopping timer.
simple  08-Jan-2014 21:20:16    Build MAV-POR-CCB-61 completed.
simple  08-Jan-2014 21:20:17    Running on server: post build plugin 'Clover Delta Calculator'
simple  08-Jan-2014 21:20:17    Running on server: post build plugin 'Build Hanging Detection Configuration'
simple  08-Jan-2014 21:20:17    Running on server: post build plugin 'NCover Results Collector'
simple  08-Jan-2014 21:20:17    Running on server: post build plugin 'Maven Dependencies Postprocessor'
simple  08-Jan-2014 21:20:17    All post build plugins have finished
simple  08-Jan-2014 21:20:17    Generating build results summary...
simple  08-Jan-2014 21:20:17    Saving build results to disk...
simple  08-Jan-2014 21:20:17    Indexing build results...
simple  08-Jan-2014 21:20:17    Finished building MAV-POR-CCB-61.
```

Please let me know if anyone can help me to resolve. I tried to compile it using `JDK 1.6` and `1.7` but still no luck. Struggling form last 2 days to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906673/import-com-sun-image-codec-jpeg) 
to see why you should not use these classes and to see how you can compile using these classes [Using internal sun classes with javac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065401/using-internal-sun-classes-with-javac/4070685)

Regards.

Comment: Thanks i resolved the issue by removing improt statement from the code. Compiled using the internal sun classes. Thanks for the solution.