# Include all Sun-proprietary classes

Tags: java, ant

I've got this [project](https://sourceforge.net/p/kablink/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/ssf/) from sf. If I run the build file I got the error:

> ...\workspace_neon\ssf\main\src\org\kablink\teaming\util\Thumbnail.java:50:
>   error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
>       [javac] import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.ImageFormatException;

I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906673/import-com-sun-image-codec-jpeg) that someone else run into similar problems. How to run the build.xml file so that javac get execute with the option -XDignore.symbol.file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [build file in which the errors occurs](https://sourceforge.net/p/kablink/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/ssf/build-common.xml) try something like this

```
            <javac ...>
               ...  
               <compilerarg value="-XDignore.symbol.file" />
            </javac>
```